# How to avoid blocking new window popup in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I've an issue on opening new page window in my Angular JS project if popup is being blocked.
Do you have any solution on bypass popup/new window blocking in IE > 8

Note; It's not a button click event to open new window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the window popup using `window.open()` you can't specially if the user has blocked popup's from their browser `that popups blocked icon at the rightmost part of the url bar` or in the browser settings then you can't do anything about it.

Comment: Yes, i am referring to 'window.open()', is there any alternate solutions to bypass user settings on browser?

Comment: unfortunately not, if they clicked ignore popups in this website then there is nothing you can do about it unless they reset the settings. Instead of making it a popup why not open it in a new tab `window.open(url, "_blank").